# SQL Select three rows with a max row from same table and joining with a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I find the maximum of `atraso` by each contract, but I cannot extract also `NUM_PARCELA`, only `contrato` because  I group by `contrato`.
Any suggestions to extract `num_parcela`, `max_atraso` by each `contrato`?

```
Select  
   a.[CONTRATO]
  ,a.[NUM_PARCELA]
  ,a.[DATA_PAGAMENTO]
  ,a.[DATA_VENCTO]
  ,b.[DATA_LIBER_CONTRATO]
  ,DATEDIFF(day, a.DATA_VENCTO, a.DATA_PAGAMENTO) as ATRASO
 INTO #temp1
  from [fprisco].[dbo].[ParcelasGrc2] as a   
inner join [fprisco].[dbo].[ContratosGrc2] as b     
on b.contrato=a.contrato   
where b.data_liber_contrato >'2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'

Select    
   contrato,   
   max(atraso) as Max_Atraso        
   from #temp1     
group by contrato  
 order by contrato desc
```

What I need is the maximum `atraso` for each `contrato` and also take which `num_parcela` matches with the maximum `atraso`. `Num_Parcela` has mutiple records for each contract, and only one matches with maximum `atraso`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be more helpful

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways how to do it, see two of them bellow:

Test case:

```
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE (contrato int, atraso int, num_parcela int)

INSERT INTO @temp1 VALUES (1,5,1)
INSERT INTO @temp1 VALUES (1,4,2)
INSERT INTO @temp1 VALUES (1,3,3)
INSERT INTO @temp1 VALUES (2,2,1)
INSERT INTO @temp1 VALUES (2,3,1)
INSERT INTO @temp1 VALUES (2,4,2)
```

First variant with group by and joining back to the original table

```
;WITH MaxAtraso AS (
    Select    
       contrato,   
       max(atraso) as Max_Atraso   
    from @temp1     
    group by contrato  
)
SELECT m.*, t.num_parcela FROM MaxAtraso m 
JOIN @temp1 t 
ON m.Max_Atraso = t.atraso AND m.contrato = t.contrato
ORDER BY contrato DESC
```

Second variant variant with ordered list using ROW_NUMBER():

```
;WITH OrderByAtraso AS (
    Select    
       contrato,  
       num_parcela,
       atraso,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contrato ORDER BY atraso DESC) rn
    from @temp1     
)
SELECT * FROM OrderByAtraso WHERE RN=1 ORDER BY contrato DESC
```

Also there is no need to create temp table just for this operation, you can rewrite like this:

```
;WITH OrderByAtraso AS (
Select  
   a.[CONTRATO]
  ,a.[NUM_PARCELA]
  ,a.[DATA_PAGAMENTO]
  ,a.[DATA_VENCTO]
  ,b.[DATA_LIBER_CONTRATO]
  ,DATEDIFF(day, a.DATA_VENCTO, a.DATA_PAGAMENTO) as ATRASO
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY contrato 
       ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day, a.DATA_VENCTO, a.DATA_PAGAMENTO) DESC) RN
from [fprisco].[dbo].[ParcelasGrc2] as a   
inner join [fprisco].[dbo].[ContratosGrc2] as b     
on b.contrato=a.contrato   
where b.data_liber_contrato >'20170228'
)
SELECT contrato, atraso as MaxAtraso, num_parcela
FROM OrderByAtraso WHERE RN=1 ORDER BY CONTRATO DESC
```